# Kali Linux fail to login after install vertion 2020.1 for VBOX amd-64

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

What I've done so far:
- Downloaded from [Offensive-security.com](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/#1572305786534-030ce714-cc3b"https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/#1572305786534-030ce714-cc3b") the Kali Linux 2020.1 VirtualBox amd64 version.

- Open the file.
- Config VBox, start machine.
- Tried to login under user: root, pasword: toor|root|password|admin but failed.
- I have tried to start it under recovery mode, so I selected the advance start options and then tried with all 4 options available (I cannot read all the text for each option because of its size).
- Non of those where the recovery mode.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [the webpage you downloaded the image from](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-image-download/), it says in red text:

> These images have a default login/password of “**kali/kali**” and may have pre-generated SSH host keys.

Comment: Thanks @telcoM - I never saw that :|

Comment: Maybe you can help me with [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583085/is-it-possible-to-use-lvm-encryption-for-entire-disk-on-kali-linux-after-install) now? @telcoM